# Cast string.Empty to (generic) T in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have a utility method which returns a strongly typed value from an old `.INI` configuration type file, with the signature

```
internal static T GetIniSetting<T>(string config, string key, T defVal = default(T))
```

I want strings to be special, in that I would like the default value for *defaultValue* to be `string.Empty`, not `default(string)` (i.e. null), in the case when the coder hasn't specified a default value.

```
if (cantFindValueInIniFile == true)
{
    if ((typeof(T) == typeof(string)) && (defaultValue == null))
    {
        // *** Code needed here - Cannot convert string to <T>***
        return (T)string.Empty; 
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

I've tried hard casting, and the `as` keyword, to no avail.

Comment: Invoking the powers of LSP didn't seem very fitting for this particular case...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'hacky' way:

```
return (T)(object)string.Empty;
```

Notes:

- Pretty safe as you have check pre-conditions.
- Performance penalty unnoticeable on reference types.

Answer (score 7):

You have to do it like this: `(T)(object)(string.Empty)`.

Also, a minor optimization is to store this in a static readonly string field so that you don't have to do the casts but one time per generic parameter (instead of per method call)

Comment: *Very* minor optimization... casts are "pretty darn fast".

Comment: @pst, true, (with reference types, at least) but why not?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the last parameter in GetIniSetting is optional, and you will get default(string) only if you don't provide anything for it. So to use string.Empty as a default string value make the call like:

```
string value = GetIniSetting<string>(config, key, string.Empty);
```

Comment: You are mistaken.  A string is a reference type, so you can pass in `null`

Comment: (And `default(string)` evaluates to `null`)